# onCreateView running twice after recreation of fragment after Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` containing only a `FrameLayout` which displays a `Fragment`. The `Fragment` only contains a `Button`.

The working of the app is that the background color of the button changes on clicking the button. The Fragment recieves the color value from an array defined in the `MainActivity`.

The Activity's code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    frag a;
    FragmentManager fm;
    static int color[] = {Color.RED,Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        a = new frag();
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = 
            (fm).beginTransaction().add(R.id.framelayout, a);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

And the Fragment code is:

```
public class frag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    View v;
    Button button;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
            i = (int) savedInstanceState.get("i");
        }

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag, container, false);
        button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setBackgroundColor(MainActivity.color[i]);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("i",i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View vx) {
        i++;
        if(i%3==0)
            i=0;
        button.setBackgroundColor(MainActivity.color[i]);
    }
}
```

**The problem is that when the screen is rotated and the fragment is recreated, the `onCreateView` runs twice one after another. The first time, it has a `non-null` `savedInstanceState`, but for the second time, the `savedInstanceState` becomes `null` (I've observed this using the debugger) . Hence, the color of the button always changes to the RED on re-creation of the fragment, which is the color at the first index of the `color Array`, and it seems as if the `state` of the app is not being saved at all.**

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onCreate` in your Activity is called again when you rotate, which means another Fragment will be created and added to your `frameLayout`. The old one will be recreated, so you have two. Check the `savedInstanceState` in the Activity onCreate. If it is not null then your Activity was recreated and it is likely that the Fragment is already there. You can also do `fragmentManager.findFragmentById(id)` and check if it's there before adding it again.

Comment: Thanks man, that works just fine. I also wonder is the old fragment recreated when we state : fragment a = new fragment(), or does the fragment manager remember the old fragment and recreates it as soon as the activity is recreated? @ono

Comment: FragmentManager recreates it because you added it the first time. So you only need to run the code after `setContentView` once.